# trying to set up a AlertDialog but keep getting errors

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

im trying to set up a alert dialog for the user to confirm that thy whant something to happen but im not sure how to set it up so i did a little looking around and found how to set it up but i still keep getting errors

```
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(settings.this)
.setTitle("hello")
.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
 //^^^^^^^it keeps telling me "The method setButton(String, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined for the type AlertDialog.Builder"

public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on OK",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                });





}
```

Comment: You need `YourActivityName.this` instead of `getActivity()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you should create your own Alert class. It would be more easier to use. My Alert class as in below:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;

public class Alert {

  private Context ctx;

  public Alert(Context ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
  }

  public void show(String str) {
    build(str);
  }

  public void show(int str) {
    build(String.valueOf(str));
  }

  public void close(AlertDialog alert) {
    alert.dismiss();
  }

  private void build(String str) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);

    builder.setMessage(str);

    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setTitle("Info");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

      }
    });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
  }
}
```

You can use this class as in below:

```
Alert alert = new Alert(SaveAndGoBack.this);
alert.show('bla bla bla');
```

Answer (score 1):

A `View.OnClickListener()` should implement `onClick` :

```
SaveAndGoBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      public void onClick(View v)
      {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SaveAndGoBack.this).setTitle(...);
        ....
      }
    });
```

Now, in order to access the enclosing Activity, you need `SaveAndGoBack.this` (assuming `SaveAndGoBack` is a sub-class of `Activity`. If it's a fragment, you'll need `SaveAndGoBack.getAcitivity()`).

`setTitle()` is a method of the builder.

Comment: that worked thx,i did change th (SaveAndGoBack.this) to my subclass and it worked lol

Answer (score 0):

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
              alert.setTitle();
```

`;` closes statement, use `,`

Refer this [example](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/09/how-to-show-alert-dialog-in-android/)